# How to fix Flutter doctor android studio plugin(Dart , Flutter) issue?

Tags: flutter, dart, plug

I installed the latest version of the Android Studio(4.1.1), the latest version of Flutter (Flutter 1.22.4 • channel stable). I installed the Dart & Flutter plugin in Android Studio. But the flutter doctor gives the plug-in is not installed issue.

[image]

Here is **flutter doctor** command result:

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.19], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
    X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

I set the android studio config path

```
   flutter config --android-studio dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"
```

But the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
flutter upgrade

flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"

flutter doctor -v
```

then if the issue still persists then just shift to the beta channel and the upgrade flutter then it will fix it.

```
flutter channel stable

flutter upgrade
```

Run the above commands in terminal.

Comment: @Sourav Ganguly, If you like it please vote and select my answer.

Answer (score 0):

(Android toolchain) issue: you need to install android studio, if already installed, you need to restart your system and then RUN the following on command prompt

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

[image]

and you will need to accept all terms and conditions.

(Android Studio) issue: you need to set the following:

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\"
```